# Find Nth term of provided sequence

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

> f(0) = p
>
> f(1) = q
>
> f(2) = r
>
> for n > 2
>
> f(n) = a*f(n-1) + b*f(n-2) + c*f(n-3) + g(n)
>
> where g(n) = n* n* (n+1)

p,q,r,a,b,c are given
The question is, How to find the nth term of this series.

Please help me in finding a better solution for this.

I have tried solving this using recursion. But that way is consuming high memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way than recursion would be [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). You just need to know the last three values for f(n).
A solution in pseudocode could look like this:

```
if n == 0:
    return p
else if n == 1:
    return q
else if n == 2:
    return r
else:    
    f_n-3 = p
    f_n-2 = q
    f_n-1 = r
    for i from 3 to n:
        f_new = a * f_n-1 + b * f_n-2 + c * f_n-3 + g(n)
        fn-1 = fn-2
        fn-2 = fn-3
        fn-3 = f_new

return f_new
```

This way you don't need to call the method recursively and keep all the values, that were calculated, on the stack, but just keep 4 variables in your memeory.

This should calculate much faster and use much less memory.

Comment: But this is still not the efficient solution. what if `n` is too big like 10^18?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for each call to `f` with `n > 2`, it results in three extra calls to `f`. For example if we call `f(5)`, we get the following calls:

```
- f(5)
    - f(4)
        - f(3)
            - f(2)
            - f(1)
            - f(0)
            - g(3)
        - f(2)
        - f(1)
        - g(4)
    - f(3)
        - f(2)
        - f(1)
        - f(0)
        - g(3)
    - f(2)
    - g(5)
```

We thus make one call `f(5)`, one call to `f(4)`, two calls to `f(3)`, four calls to `f(2)`, three calls to `f(1)`, and two calls to `f(0)`.

Since we make multiple calls to for example `f(3)`, it thus means that each time this will cost resources, especially since `f(3)` itself will make extra calls.

We can let Python store the result of a function call, and return the result, for example with the [**`lru_cache`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). This technique is called *memoization*:

```
from functools import lru_cache

def g(n):
    return n * n * (n+1)

@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def f(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return (p, q, r)[n]
    else:
        return a*f(n-1) + b*f(n-2) + c*f(n-3) + g(n)
```

This will result in a call graph like:

```
- f(5)
    - f(4)
        - f(3)
            - f(2)
            - f(1)
            - f(0)
            - g(3)
        - g(4)
    - g(5)
```

So now we will only calculate `f(3)` once, the `lru_cache` will store it in the cache, and if we call `f(3)` a second time, we will never evaluate `f(3)` itself, the cache will return the pre-computed value.

The above here can however be optimized, since we each time call `f(n-1)`, `f(n-2)` and `f(n-3)`, we only need to store the last three values, and each time calculate the next value based on the last three values, and shift the variables, like:

```
def f(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return (p, q, r)[n]
    f3, f2, f1 = p, q, r
    for i in range(3, n+1):
        f3, f2, f1 = f2, f1, a * f1 + b * f2 + c * f3 + g(i)
    return f1
```

Comment: In the iterative version, shouldn't `g` be evaluated at the current index, instead of only the final `n`?