# Compute: f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3) + n * n * (n + 1)

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

For the recurrence relation:

```
f(0) = p
f(1) = q
f(2) = r
For n > 2,
f(n) = a * f(n - 1) + b * f(n - 2) + c * f(n - 3) + n * n * (n + 1)
```

Given some **n** <= 10 ^ 18, I want to find out **f(n)** using an approach that runs in **O(log n)** time.

If f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3), we could solve it in O(Log n) time using Matrix Exponentiation. But the n * n * (n + 1) term complicates the problem.

Comment: Great idea! What is your question?

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing? Or your actual question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Nth term of provided sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612225/find-nth-term-of-provided-sequence)

Comment: With memoization it's still linear time, so that's not sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That matrix equation can still be set up, but some powers of `n` need to be in it as well:

```
|F(n-0)|   | a, b, c, 1, 1, 0, 0 |   |F(n-1)|
|F(n-1)|   | 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |   |F(n-2)|
|F(n-2)|   | 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 |   |F(n-3)|
|(n+1)³| = | 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1 | * | n³   |
|(n+1)²|   | 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1 |   | n²   |
| n+1  |   | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 |   | n    |
| 1    |   | 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 |   | 1    |
```

Then do exponentiation by squaring, and finally multiply the resulting matrix by this vector:

```
[r, q, p, 27, 9, 3, 1].T
```

As usual this can all be done with modular arithmetic if the final answer is requested modulo `M`, which it probably will be otherwise the values get way too big for `n` near 10<sup>18</sup>.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Could you please tell me how you approached the problem? I was stuck on it for a long time.

Comment: @Tanmay I took this formulation from the Fibonacci matrix trick, then modified it a bit with the extra `F(n-3)` and the powers of `n`